# Building a Linux C++ API as a Windows DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, dll, cygwin

I'm attempting to build the [C++ Avro API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/cpp/html/index.html) as a DLL so I can use the Avro generated header files in a Visual Studio project. I'm able to build Avro in Windows using Cygwin, so the next step is to convert the Avro API into a DLL and use it along with the `cygwin1.dll` in my project (not entirely clear on how this would work either).

I've been looking at various online guides on [how to build the DLL using cmake (by VTK)](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/BuildingWinDLL) (since cmake is generally used to build Avro) and I wanted to make sure that what I'm attempting to do is actually feasible before spending a ton of time trying to do it. I've also noticed that the [cygwin guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) indicates that the gcc compiler can already build DLLs:

```
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

Generally in windows we have to specify which functions/classes needs to be exported by using the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute where appropriate. Could anybody please clarify how it's all supposed to come together:

1. In order to build my DLL with Cygwin, do I have to mark all of the functions/classes with the export attribute as shown in the VTK guide or can I just do something to tell the gcc compiler to output a DLL without using the export attributes (i.e. change the cmake options in the `CMakeList.txt` file)?
2. Once I generate a DLL from cygwin, then in my Visual Studio project I must reference both `my.dll` and the `cygwin1.dll`? Is it "*that simple*" or am I missing something?

If I have to mark all of the functions/classes in Avro with the export attribute, then I can imagine it will be a significantly more involved task since [Avro has a decent amount of classes](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/cpp/html/annotated.html). If I don't mark the functions/classes with the export attribute and I use GCC to output a DLL, then will the necessary export symbols be generated so they can be used in a VS project?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use dll compiled with g++ in msvc. Not if it exports anything more than `extern "C"` functions. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw)

Comment: I can't actually help with the main problem, but: get rid of the `cygwin1.dll` dependency if you possibly can.  (You can do this without ceasing to use Cygwin as a build environment.)  There's no obvious reason why Avro or Avro-generated code should *need* a fake Unix environment, and mixing Cygwin-dependent DLLs with DLLs that expect the normal Windows runtime environment is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Zack but Avro includes some GNU libraries that I can only get with Cygwin. I'm kinda stuck in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample project that attempts to generate the DLL and this is what I had in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
PROJECT(DLLTest)

# Allow the developer to select if Dynamic or Static libraries are built
OPTION (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build Shared Libraries" ON)

# Set the LIB_TYPE variable to SHARED
SET (LIB_TYPE SHARED)

#IF (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  # User wants to build Dynamic Libraries, so change the LIB_TYPE variable to CMake keyword 'SHARED'
#  SET (LIB_TYPE SHARED)
#ENDIF (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)

# Create a target for the library
ADD_LIBRARY(DLLTest ${LIB_TYPE} hello.cpp)

SET( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin" )
SET( LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib" )
```

The resulting output is a DLL (*.dll) and a shared library (*.a). However, I wasn't able to successfully link with the DLL, although I should be able to according to an answer on the cygwin FAQ: http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.programming.html#faq.programming.msvs-mingw

The above link also provides instructions on how to generate the .def and the .lib (see the links for more info on why they're needed).