# Given .dll, .lib, and .h, and would like to write a C program using a function in the DLL

Tags: c, gcc, dll, static-libraries, undefined-reference

So, I have TVZLib.h, TVZlib.dll, and TVZlib.lib, and I am using gcc to compile the following program (it's a simple test case). The complier gives me the error:

```
"undefined reference to '_imp__TVZGetNavigationMatrix'"
```

Yet. when I comple the program with a different type of parameter for the function's call, it complains that it's not the correct parameter (requires *float). To me, that means that it at least has found the function, as it knows what it wants.

From my research, I can tell that people think it's to do with the linking of the library, or the order in which I link, but I've tried all of the gcc commands in all combinations, and all give me the same error, so I'm desperate for some help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TVZLib.h"

int main() {
    float floatie = 2;
    float *ptr = &floatie;
    TVZGetNavigationMatrix(ptr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

My compiler command:

```
gcc dlltest.c -L. TVZLib.lib
```

---

[The header file (TVZLib.h).](http://pastebin.com/VSr5Aj3R)

And the direct output:

```
C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccuDpoiE.o:dlltest.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `_imp__TVZGetNavigationMatrix'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Can you post your compiler command.

Comment: I added the simplest one that gives me that error.

Comment: `The complier gives me the error`.  No, it is a linker error.  You'll need to find out what names *do* exist in tvzlib.lib.  If you see the plain name without the _imp__ prefix then using the dllimport attribute in the .h file wasn't correct.

Comment: So, you're saying it's an error in the files I was given? They're third party, I had no hand in making them.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've been compiling natively on Windows...

Did you intend to link statically against TVZlib.lib? That's not happening.
By default, gcc will pick the dynamic version of a library if it finds both a static and a dynamic lib. If you want to force gcc to link statically, you can use the `-static` option.

If memory serves me right the `_imp__` prefix is a sign that a DLL was loaded (`_imp__` symbol prefix is used for the trampoline function that calls into the DLL).

Comment: Thanks for replying! 
As for the dynamic/static linking, honestly, I'm not 100% sure about the difference, nor do I really care, as long as it works. Given that I have both types of libraries, I should have an option, right?

Unfortunately, using `-static` gives the same error.

Comment: Uhm. Looking at the compiler command that you provided, I think you forgot to name the library name (is done with the (lower caps L) `-l` flag. Something like `gcc dlltest.c -o dlltest -L. -static -lTVZLib` or some such.

Comment: After googling around, I've come to believe that gcc can't link directly to .lib files (see this [MinGW wiki entry](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs)). They're suggesting to use MinGW's _reimp_ tool to generate a .dll from a .lib. Also, check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! However, I already have the .dll, gcc just doesn't seem to be linking to it?