# Why does MSVC need an import library (.lib) for a .dll when MinGW doesn't?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, winapi, mingw

I'm a little confused as to why a 3rd party .dll I'm using comes with a .lib file labeled as an "import library." When I run the program, I just place the .dll in the same directory as the executable and it works. I'm using MinGW.

Could someone explain why the .dll comes with a .lib import library if I don't even need it? How would I even use it and where should I put it if I did use it with MinGW?

**I read up on it and it looks like the .lib file is not needed by MinGW (what I'm using) and *is* needed by MSVC. Why is this?**

P.S. If I wanted to put a .dll in a directory other than the directory containing the executable, could I put a line in the .pro file to point to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Import Library work? Details?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)

Comment: I read that. It does not get at the question about MinGW and MSVC requirements, though.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL](https://web.archive.org/web/20200519042130/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL), MinGW can guess the information that's contained in a `.lib` (DLL name, exported entries' names and ABI) from the corresponding `.h` file and the DLL itself.

According to [http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504021857/http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries), this works "for all DLLs created with MinGW and also a few others".

In cases when it can't guess correctly, you still need to provide a `.lib` file. The latter link has instructions on how to generate one by hand if you haven't got a pristine one.

The former link refers to `ld` docs for a more in-depth description. Specifically, it's at the [ld and WIN32 (cygwin/mingw)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.26/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32) node, *"direct linking to a dll"* section. Among other things, it outlines cases when a `.lib` is necessary:

- until recently, direct linking didn't work for exported data entries
- if a `.lib` contains pure static objects (e.g. `cygwinX.dll`)
- if exported entries do not conform to mangling rules (e.g. Win32 libraries)