# Can't load a dll file using LoadLibrary function

Tags: c++, dll, dynamic-linking

So I was trying to make a program that dynamically creates a dll file and loads it into the program and calls it.
Here is my code for 
createFile:

```
    void createFile(std::string data, std::string name) {
    std::ofstream file;
    name += ".cpp";
    file.open(name,std::ofstream::out);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        file << data;
        std::cout << "File saved successfully" << std::endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    }
```

compile:

```
void compile(std::string name) {
    std::string temp;
    temp = "c++.exe " + name + ".cpp -o dll/" + name + ".dll -shared -fPIC";

    system(temp.c_str());
}
```

loadFunc:

```
typedef void (*function)(const char*);
void loadFunc(LPCSTR name, LPCSTR func) {
    HMODULE temp;
    function __cdecl myproc;
    temp = LoadLibraryA(name);
    if (temp != NULL) {
        std::cout << "\nDll is loaded";
        myproc = (function) GetProcAddress(temp, func);
    if (myproc !=NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "\nFunction is loaded\n";
            (myproc)("Somthing here");
        }
        // Free the DLL module.
    FreeLibrary(temp);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I compile a dll using visual studio 2019 it works just fine, but if I compile a dll file using gcc or c++ or g++ it doesn't load the dll. So I tried using dependency walker to see the difference between two dll files(one made with gcc and another with visual studio). I saw the file structures were different. dll made with gcc had larger size than the one made with visual studio. Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:**

So after doing some trial and error, I have found that only dll files that have C libraries work. I don't know why. I tried using iostream earlier, but it always failed to load and on the other hand when I used stdio.h it worked fine.

dllfile.cpp(with iostream):

```
#ifdef __cpluplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <iostream>

__declspec(dllexport) void print(const char *x){
      std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

dllfile.cpp(with stdio):

```
#ifdef __cpluplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void print(const char *x){
      printf("%s",x);
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: What is the result of `GetLastError`

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: your gcc/g++ builds are using the same architecture (i.e. x86 or x64) as your exe and your vs2019 build, *right* ?

Comment: yes they are both of the same architecture

Comment: Another possibly silly question: Are the two output DLLs in the same place (as each other)?

Comment: GetLastError() returns 193

Comment: Yes they are in the same place.

Comment: 193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` `%1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: I tried with both x64 and x86 architecture to be sure if it's the problem still it doesn't print "Dll is loaded". And GetLastError() prints 126 for x64 and 193 for x86 version.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting that though. I manually tried to compile the dll using "c++ dllfile.cpp -o dllfile.dll -shared -fPIC"

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) for the meaning of the codes

Comment: Oh yeah. So 126 code was returned because dll wasn't in the x64 folder. So I copied there. After that it still gave me 193 on x64 version as well.

Comment: [This might be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw).

Comment: Okay, so after researching different things I have found out that c++ libraries are hard to export as dlls. When I use printf instead of std::cout, it works like a charm. So I tried to implement it using std::cout so in the end due to name mangling my function overlaps with another library function and causes access violation(That's what I think) when I load the dll into the file.

Comment: 126 probably tries to tell you that the OS can't find the runtime support library you need for g++ builds.