# Why does the compiler throw "undefined reference to..." error in this case?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to run the code in CLion that worked perfectly in Visual Studio. The program has an external dependency - OpenCV 4.2.0 library. I've never worked wtih CMake before so i searched for the solution on how to link the library to the project. I am using MingW-w64 as my environment. CMake builds without a single warning, but when compiling the project it throws an error "undefined reference to (put whatever function from OpenCV here). I spent 5 hours trying to understand what's wrong, looking for solution on forums and, of course, here, but i've failed to find the root of the problem. I created another project just to simplify debugging. Both of the projects throw the same errors with the same CMakeLists.txt files.
Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
project(SOMETHINF)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(OpenCV_DIR "E:\\LIBS\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc15\\lib")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${OpenCV_LIBS})
add_executable(SOMETHINF main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SOMETHINF ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

As you can see i put **message()** in there to see if it finds the files and it does:

```
opencv_calib3dopencv_coreopencv_dnnopencv_features2dopencv_flannopencv_gapiopencv_highguiopencv_imgcodecsopencv_imgprocopencv_mlopencv_objdetectopencv_photoopencv_stitchingopencv_videoopencv_videoioopencv_world
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/SOMETHINF/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Here is the code (there's other unnecessary stuff just because):
[image]

And what i get trying to compile it:
[image]

Has anyone faced something similar before?

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages to use screenshots for code, logs and other textual information. Please, instead of your two logs paste the **text** instead. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using msvc libraries, but if you use MinGW compiler it will not work.
You can read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw) to understand why.

Providing the right libraries should fix your problem ! Usually the owner of the project provide msvc 12/14/15/16 and mingw binaries. If you don't have them I found [this unofficial build](https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build) with a quick search.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew the issue wasn't with the code but rather with some technical subtleties. I'll make sure to get the proper version of the library that will suit the environment i chose, you get your upvote and accepted answer, i appreciate your help a lot :)