# MSVC programs calling an MinGW DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, mingw

Following [this short tutorial](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls), I get stuck at the stage of linking the DLL built by MinGW. Here are the two simple source code files I use for practice purpose.

foo.cpp for foo.dll

```
const char *greeting(void)
{
    return "Hello, World!";
}
```

main.cpp for main.exe

```
#include <cstdio>
const char * greeting(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::printf("%s\n", greeting());
    return 0;
}
```

I ran all the commands in MSYS2 on Windows 10. Below is the commands and their outputs. It looks time-wasting long, but really only the last 2 lines matter.

```
### Generate foo.def and foo.dll.
$ g++ foo.cpp -shared -Wall -Wl,--output-def=foo.def -o foo.dll
$ cat foo.def
EXPORTS
    _Z8greetingv @1
### Generate foo.lib and foo.exp.
$ lib /machine:x64 /def:foo.def
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.27.29112.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library foo.lib and object foo.exp
### Try to generate .exe file.
$ cl main.cpp foo.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.27.29112 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.27.29112.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64"
main.obj
foo.lib
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl greeting(void)" (?greeting@@YAPEBDXZ) referenced in function main
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

As you can see, the last 2 lines is the problem. It will work, if change the calling convention with `extern "C"`. So, apparently something went wrong with this mysterious calling convention stuff. I'm new to MSVC toolset by the way. So, maybe this is a stupid question. Any hint? Thanks.

EDIT: Please note that the codes above are supposed to be compiled as C++ codes instead of C codes. They look simple and, of course, there isn't any object-oriented code in them. They are just an experiment, but I'm planing to put C++ classes into .dll file if it's doable. Therefore, I'm wondering if it's still possible when name mangling is taken into account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking to MSVC DLL from MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw)

Comment: @BenjaminBihler No, the direction is opposite.

Comment: The important point is this sentence from the accepted answer "The difference is, c++ functions are always exported with names in a mangled form that is specific to a particular version of the compiler." Therefore DLLS with **C** functions are compatible, but DLLs with **C++ classes** are not compatible. The only way to make them compatible is to write interface `extern C` functions (which are again **C**) and hide the C++ classes.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler You're right. Thanks for the answer.