Linking C++ VisualStudio libraries in a MingW project
We have a C++ project with lots of dependencies, and that contains some POSIXisms (like pid_t) and we are looking for ways of building the dependencies with VisualStudio tools, while building our own project with MingW (again, due POSIXisms).
So far, building the dependencies with VisualStudio tools works fine, but linking those libraries with our project fails.
One example is the oneTBB library: When compiling our project with this dependency enabled, we get a lot of link issues, like
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: src/OpenFOAM/CMakeFiles/OpenFOAM.dir/meshes/polyMesh/polyMeshTetDecomposition/polyMeshTetDecomposition.C.obj:polyMeshTetDecomposition.C:(.text$_ZN4Foam9syncTools20syncBoundaryFaceListIiNS_7maxEqOpIiEENS_13mapDistribute9transfomEEEvRKNS_8polyMeshERNS_5UListIT_EERKT0_RKT1_bb[_ZN4Foam9syncTools20syncBoundaryFaceListIiNS_7maxEqOpIiEENS_13mapDistribute9transformEEEvRKNS_8polyMeshERNS_5UListIT_EERKT0_RKT1_bb+0x827): undefined reference to `tbb::detail::r1::destroy(tbb::detail::d1::task_group_context&)'

But using dumpbin in the lib, we can see that the function is present in the .lib file:
C:\Users>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64
\dumpbin.exe" /exports tbb.lib | findstr /c:"destroy"
                  ?destroy@r1@detail@tbb@@YAXAEAVglobal_control@d1@23@@Z (void __cdecl tbb::detail::r1::destroy(class tbb::detail::d1::global_control &))
                  ?destroy@r1@detail@tbb@@YAXAEAVtask_group_context@d1@23@@Z (void __cdecl tbb::detail::r1::destroy(class tbb::detail::d1::task_group_context &))

The link has a call for this lib, in the form of /home/project/ThirdParty-win /platforms/linuxmingw_w64Gcc/opentbb-2021.7.0/lib/tbb12.lib
(In summary: We can compile the code fine, but when linking we get a missing symbol, even when the symbol is in the .lib generated, and the .lib is being added to the link process).
My initial conclusion is that VisualStudio and MingW do not produce/generate the same mangling for C++ symbols, and that's why the linking fails.
Am I right? Is there any option to make either system generate symbols in a way that the other can see?

VS and MingW do different name mangling. You can try extern "C", but it's generally better to get libraries from the same compiler.

bigger problem, standard libraries are not compatible, neither are allocators, if a struct is deallocated in a function produced by a different compiler than the allocating one the whole thing will crash .... try to use only 1 compiler for the entire application to guarantee a stable ABI.

Why do you need VS in the first place? You can build oneTBB directly with MinGW (MSYS2 does that).

Is this perhaps relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw

In general you can't mix c++ libraries between compilers, if you're careful and your libraries only have c interfaces then you can do it with DLLs, static libraries is a whole other mine field
