# g++ undefined reference to error

Tags: visual-studio, dll, g++

I am linking a g++ compiled test client with my a dll that was compiled with Visual Studio 2008. It generates the following error message.

```
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `ICD_Create(char*)@4'
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `ICD_Remove()@0'
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `ICD_Open(unsigned int, unsigned int, char, unsigned int, unsigned int)@20'
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `ICD_Close()@0'
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `ICD_Command(char const*)@4'
client2.o:client2.c:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `ICD_Synchronize()@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there a conflict between g++ and visual studio libraries? am I using the wrong DLL interface?

**Update:**

The g++ command is g++ -o client2.out client2.0 i-cut_driver.dll

Comment: can you include your GCC command that lead to this error?

Comment: Is this C, C++ or both? Maybe you are missing `extern "C"` in your declarations?

Comment: I am using WINAPI in the function declaration (which I believe is a macro to __stdcall). Is this the convention that Visual Studio DLLs use?

Comment: @Peretz: DLLs can have different calling conventions. If your library is written in C, add `extern "C"` to your declarations. If your library is written in C++, you will have a lot of problems calling it with different compiler. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796209/how-to-link-to-vs2008-generated-libs-from-g/1801994#1801994).

Answer (score 0):

In general, C++ code produced with different C++ compilers is not link-compatible. C++ code built with `g++` and VisualStudio almost certainly isn't.

Comment: @Banthar, @Employed: Thank you for the note. So, I am kind of confused with all these DLLs configurations. I see there are COM DLLs, .NET DLLs, standard DLLs, MFC DLLs, specific C++ implementations. I know that .NET and COM can work together, and standard can be called from several other ones. But, is there are a rule of thumb, or general scheme to know what can be linked with what?.